# PHP Fatal error when trying to install Cron in Laravel 4

Tags: symfony, laravel, laravel-4, cron, cron-task

I am trying to install Cron with laravel 4. I followed these instructions:

http://packalyst.com/packages/package/liebig/cron#addjob

However I got stuck when trying to migrate the database using command:

*php artisan migrate --package="liebig/cron"*

And this is the error:

*PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Liebig\Cron\CronServiceProvider' not found in /var/www/domain.com/htdocs/SP/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 157
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'Liebig\Cron\CronServiceProvider' not found","file":"/var/www/domain.com/htdocs/SP/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php","line":157}}*

Yes, I have added Liebig\Cron\CronServiceProvider  to providers in app.php

Any ideas? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/liebig/cron/issues/62

Comment: Oh and did you try `composer dumpautoload` just checking

Comment: You may want to check that the cron package installed properly as well, does it show up in your `composer.json` file?